# How do irrational numbers give incommensurate potential (in lattice models)?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, lattice-model

I am trying to understand [Aubry-Andre model](http://chaos.if.uj.edu.pl/~delande/Lectures/?4-aubry-andre-model,28). It has the following form
$$H = \sum_n c_n^\dagger c_{n+1}+H.C.+V\sum_n \cos{(2\pi\beta n)}c_n^\dagger c_n$$

[This reference (at 3rd page)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/6/1/070/data) says that if $\beta$ is irrational (rational) then period of potential is quasi-periodic incommensurate (periodic commensurate) with underlying lattice period.

**Question 1:** What does incommensurate potential mean here?

**Question 2:** How does irrational $\beta$ guarantee that potential is quasi-period incommensurate with underlying lattice?

Further more, this reference says that with irrational $\beta$ (they are taking inverse of Golden mean i.e. $(\sqrt 5 - 1)/2)$ to avoid the unwanted boundary effects, we have to take system of size of any number from Fibonacci series.

**Question 3:** How does system of size of any Fibonacci series' number avoid unwanted boundary effects?

Comment: Your pdf link broken; it links to a file named untitled.pdf on someone's desktop.

Comment: @DavidHammen I am sorry. I have updated it. Thank you for pointing it out.